# how array includes function work in js

Tags: javascript

Dose **includes** function complete loop throw each array item even if required item was in the beginning of array ?? can anyone explain that ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function search(array,requiredItem) {
   if(array.includes(requiredItem)){
       return true;
   }else{
       return false;
   }
}
search(['alaa','ali','ammar','omar','alia'],'alaa');
});
```

Comment: No, it stops searching as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: For further info on what 4castle states, you can find in step 7b of the spec where the loop exits as soon as a match is found: [Reference](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array include in javascript stops as soon as the search element is found. It is using an algorythm called **SameValueZero** algorythm.  Here is the code behind the function **includes()**:

```
// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
    value: function(searchElement, fromIndex) {

      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If len is 0, return false.
      if (len === 0) {
        return false;
      }

      // 4. Let n be ? ToInteger(fromIndex).
      //    (If fromIndex is undefined, this step produces the value 0.)
      var n = fromIndex | 0;

      // 5. If n ≥ 0, then
      //  a. Let k be n.
      // 6. Else n < 0,
      //  a. Let k be len + n.
      //  b. If k < 0, let k be 0.
      var k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

      function sameValueZero(x, y) {
        return x === y || (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y));
      }

      // 7. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let elementK be the result of ? Get(O, ! ToString(k)).
        // b. If SameValueZero(searchElement, elementK) is true, return true.
        if (sameValueZero(o[k], searchElement)) {
          return true;
        }
        // c. Increase k by 1. 
        k++;
      }

      // 8. Return false
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This is the polyfill code, not the actual `includes()` code

Comment: whats the big O of include ?